Draining pipe to outside faucet
I have an outside faucet with a ~20 foot pipe leading to the 1/4-turn shutoff valve in the laundry room. I've followed this procedure for years: shut the valve, open the outside faucet, unscrew the little knurled cap on the shutoff valve and catch the flow of water into a bucket as the pipe drains, then close the outside faucet. As the flow is ending I sometimes gently raise the pipe to get more water to come out.
I had the outside faucet closed for a few years as I don't use it anymore but recently had to open the valve for a contractor to have a water supply. When he finished, I set out to use my usual procedure for draining the pipe. This time, however, when I removed the knurled cap after shutting off the valve and opening the outside faucet only a few drops of water came out. Raising the pipe didn't do anything. If I tapped with my finger on the opening that the knurled cap covers, a few drops would come out as if it were ready to start flowing but nothing happened unless I kept tapping. In the end, I got about 1/4 cup of water out of the pipe
So what's different now? What would cause this unexpected behavior?
Thanks.

I don't get it. From the main, which fixture is served first? The laundry or the outside faucet (spigot)? Also what's the reason for your "procedure" to drain the pipe? Winterizing? Is this pipe run on the exterior of the house?

The laundry. The pipe is inside, the faucet is outside on cinder block with a short, ~1-inch narrow pipe leading to it. I don't know how likely it is, but since moving into the house many years ago I got in the habit of draining the pipe leading to the faucet to prevent bursting in winter. The long pipe to the faucet is above the ceiling of the finished basement. Every time I had done this and unscrewed  the knurled cap there was a steady flow of water for many seconds. This time there was basically nothing. Just wondering what would explain that.

maybe there's no water in the pipe, try blowing air through it

But why would there not be water in the pipe? There always was when I did this procedure.

I think I may have solved this mystery. I remembered that at first I didn't exactly do the procedure outlined in my question. I shut the valve but instead of then opening the outside faucet I opened what I now know is called the bleeder cap. As nothing much came out I realized that I hadn't opened the outside faucet. I put back the bleeder cap, went outside to open the faucet, then came back inside to open the bleeder valve and as described nothing came out.
I suspect what happened was some air got in through the bleeder cap which then prevented water to pass through it. Today, to get back to the initial state, I opened the valve, unscrewed the bleeder cap a little to let some water come out of it, went outside and opened the faucet to let some water flow out. Water came out as expected and there was also a short burst of air. I closed the valve then went inside to do the procedure as outlined in my question.
When I opened the bleeder cap a nice stream of water came out as expected. So it seems the procedure has to be done in the correct order. Makes sense?
